# Get string from specific XML file [Android Development]

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-xml

I want to have a separate string file for different areas of my Android app. How can I refer to a specific file to pull the value from? For example, what can I add to `@string/hello_world` to get the value from **values>homescreen-strings.xml** *and no other file*?

I'll reiterate, since apparently I wasn't able to get my point across:
How can I scope the variable names to stay within a file, so I can use the same variable name in other files within `res>values`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a string resource through `R.string.mystring` or `@string/mystring`. It is not required that string must be in the file `strings.xml`. It can be in another file, e.g. `mystrings.xml`. However, the only requirement is that the file `mystrings.xml` must be in the directory `res/values/`.

**Besides**, you cannot have two string resources with the same name, and it doesn't matter whether they are in different XML files. If you try that in Android Studio, you will get the following error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the functionality you described, it's just not what I am trying to accomplish. I apparently wasn't clear enough in my initial question, so I added some clarification.

Comment: You cannot have two string resources with the same name, and it doesn't matter whether they are in different XML files. If you try that in Android Studio, you will get the following error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.`